# Sym-linking windows with linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu-10.10, symbolic-link

Is it possible to make a sym-link in linux that can be used by windows? I have a dual boot system of Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows 7 and I want to move my AppData folder to another drive. I was planning on copying the folder to a different drive and then sym-linking to that location, but I cant because a driver is using the AppData folder. Is there a way for my to sym-link the AppData folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Windows 7 and Linux's NTFS-3G driver respect symbolic links created with the [`mklink` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.10).aspx) on Windows.  For more information on Linux's support of NTFS links and junction points, [see this article](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/junction-points-and-symbolic-links/).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you can boot to a Win7 installation disc (or Startup Repair disc), pull up a shell, and move the folder/create your junction from there.

I know ntfs-3g-advanced supports junctions under Linux, but I don't know if it is limited to parsing junctions, or if it can create them.

Bear in mind that this may break the servicing stack (preventing Windows Updates or causing them to fail catastrophically), so keep good backups.